# I want to add form validation with alert box in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

When I click to submit, some input fields are empty. So I want an alert box to display for entering the value to the empty input field. Screenshot image: prnt.sc/pjwf7a

HTML code:

```
    <div class="contact-form" id="form-details">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" v-model="newName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" v-model="newName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" v-model="newName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group messagebox">
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message..." v-model="newName"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit-btn">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn_default" value="Free Online Course" v-on:click="addName">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Vue script:

```
    var formalert = new Vue({

    el: '#form-details',
    data: {
            newName:''
        },

    methods: { 
        addName() {
            alert('Enter Your Name');
                }
        },

});
```

Comment: How it does not work in detail? I mean, is it nt clickable, or alerting whatever the name input is or vice versa? Currently, your question is way too general, as *does not work* phrase always is.

Comment: When I click to submit, some input fields are empty. So I want an alert box to display for entering the value to the empty input field. https://prnt.sc/pjwf7a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this code:

```
input type="submit" class="btn btn_default" value="Free Online Course" v-on:click="addName"</br>
```

To:

```
input type="button" class="btn btn_default" value="Free Online Course" v-on:click="addName"
```

Hope it is useful for you :)